# add geom_freqpoly in existing geo_histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have experimental and theoretical results. Below is a histogram code of experimental results. I have predefined my bins edges `breaks = seq(-4, 4, 0.1)`

How do I add theoretical results using `geom_freqpoly()` in the background for comparison. I want it to use same predefined bins edges.

```
library(tidyverse)

experimental <- rnorm(1000, sd = 0.8)
theoretical <- rnorm(1000, sd = 1.2)
test <- c(rep("A", 500), rep("B", 500))
tbl <- tibble(experimental, theoretical, test)

ggplot(data = tbl,
       aes(x = experimental)) + 
  geom_histogram(breaks = seq(-4, 4, 0.1),
                 alpha = 0.9,
                 color = "black",
                 size = 0.2) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-4, 4),
                     oob = scales::oob_squish) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  facet_grid(. ~ test)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
ggplot(data = tbl,
       aes(x = experimental)) + 
  geom_freqpoly(aes(x=theoretical, y=..density..), breaks=seq(-4,4,1)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), 
                 breaks = seq(-4, 4, 0.1),
                 alpha = 0.5,
                 color = "black",
                 size = 0.2) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-4, 4),
                     oob = scales::oob_squish) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  facet_grid(. ~ test)
```

[image]